# Insert into table from another table using while loop and limit,offset

Tags: mysql

My task is to insert data into a table from another table batch wise as the original table contains more than 4 million records and it slows down the other process.

To be noted- i know 'insert into select * from..'syntax

So i have tried the following procedure ,can some one tell me is it correct.Because i have not seen while loop used along with limit and offset.

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_name] as
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
BEGIN

DECLARE @value INT;
declare @count int;
 SET @value = 0;
 set @count=(select count(1) from new_table);
 select @count;
WHILE @value <1
begin 
insert into new_table
select *,0 from old_table  where error=1
order by id offset @count rows fetch next 1000 rows only

SET @value = @value + 1;
end;
END;
```

The names in stored procedure are just for representation.

Comment: only 1000 records will be inserted and while loop will only run once  based upon your `@value <1` condition.

Comment: yes that's like 1 batch of 1000 records,if i want to increase the records to be inserted then i will change @value<1 condition.

Answer (score 0):

Your `WHILE` loop won't terminate if the table ends before your batches end.

Also, you may want to key your batch starts and ends from `id` values rather than plain row counts.

This approach to batch handling will be slightly more robust:

```
DECLARE @rowcount INT;
SET @rowcount = 1;
DECLARE @value INT;
SET @value = 0;
DECLARE @count INT;
SET @count=(select count(1) from new_table);
DECLARE @batchstart  INT;
SET @batchstart = -1;
IF @count <= 0 THEN
   SELECT MAX(id) FROM new_table INTO @batchstart;
END IF

/* now @batchstart holds the largest id value already in new_table */
WHILE @value <1 AND @rowcount > 0
BEGIN
    INSERT into new_table
    SELECT *,0 from old_table
     WHERE id > @batchstart
       AND error = 1
     ORDER BY id 
     FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY;

     /* here we fetch the number of rows actually processed.
      * if it's zero, no more rows to process from old_table */
     SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO @rowcount;
     SET @value = @value + 1;

     /* find out where the next batch, if any, should start */
     SELECT MAX(id) FROM new_table INTO @batchstart;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks willsurely go via this approach.The main lesson I learnt is to consider column values rather than row count